# Search for String in Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am trying to make auto suggest in angular Js, if I have to find a string in an array i can use indexOf method,based on index value,I can get the suggestions.
But how should I match string in an array of Object?

I have an array of object

```
  $scope.array=[
            {"name":"stackoverflow","id":1},
            {"name":"sunny","id":2},
            {"name":"san","id":3},
            {"name":"bat","id":4},
            {"name":"ball","id":5}
          ]
```

so In a text box if I type "st",it should give me result in an array [{stackoverflow","id":1}]

if I enter "ba",it should give me result in an array [{"name":"bat","id":4},
        {"name":"ball","id":5}]

inside Controller

```
$scope.searchString=function(){
//what logic should I write here?
}
```

Comment: You're better off using a library that provides this sort of functionality out of the box. In fact, I think there are many angular plugins that do exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `filter` for that

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
 <div ng-repeat="item in array | filter:{'name':searchText}">
 {{item}}
</div>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.array=[
            {"name":"stackoverflow","id":1},
            {"name":"sunny","id":2},
            {"name":"san","id":3},
            {"name":"bat","id":4},
            {"name":"ball","id":5}
          ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
 <div ng-repeat="item in array | filter:{'name':searchText}">
 {{item}}
</div>
</div>
```

using custom function

```js
angular.module("app",[])
    .controller("ctrl",function($scope){

    var backUp=[
                {"name":"stackoverflow","id":1},
                {"name":"sunny","id":2},
                {"name":"san","id":3},
                {"name":"bat","id":4},
                {"name":"ball","id":5}
              ]
    $scope.array = angular.copy(backUp)
    $scope.changeText = function(){ 
      $scope.array = backUp.filter(function(o){      
       return o.name.startsWith($scope.searchText)
      })
    }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="changeText()"/>
     <div ng-repeat="item in array">
     {{item}}
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You got my vote. In case he doesn't feel like styling the autocomplete box, he may consider using a library like: https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete

Comment: Guys i dont want to use any directive, i want the logic in my controller.

Comment: @Sanjay B create a custom filter. check out the second demo

Answer (score 2):

Here are your solutions,

**Pure JS:**

```
/*
input -> object array
searchStr -> string 
keyToSearch -> string array - match to restrict within given keys //eg:['name','id','somekey']
*/
function filterObjectArray(input, searchStr, keysToSearch){
  return input.filter(function(obj){
     var hasMatch = false;
     var hasKeySearch = (keysToSearch && keysToSearch.length)
     for(k in obj){
        if(!hasMatch){
           hasMatch = (!hasKeySearch || (hasKeySearch && keysToSearch.indexOf(k))) && (new RegExp(searchStr, 'gi')).test(obj[k]);
        }
     }
     return hasMatch;
  });
}

console.log(filterObjectArray($scope.array, 'ba')); //[{"name":"bat","id":4},{"name":"ball","id":5}]
console.log(filterObjectArray($scope.array, '1')); //[{"name":"stackoverflow","id":1}]
console.log(filterObjectArray($scope.array, 's', ['name'])); //[{"name":"stackoverflow","id":1},{"name":"sunny","id":2},{"name":"san","id":3}]
```

**With Angular,**

**Solution 1:**

You can use `$filter` service in your method.

```
$scope.searchString = function(str){
   return $filter('filter')($scope.array, str);
};
```

**Solution 2:**

With `filter` in template,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
<div ng-repeat="item in array | filter:{'name':searchText}">
 {{item}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, this should work:

```
$scope.searchString=function(str){
  const results = [];
  const len = str.length;
  for(const item of $scope.array){
    const test = item.name.substr(0, len);
    if(str === test){
      results.push(item);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Though, the method regarding filters from @sachila probably makes sense in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a .reduce() on the array, then check each object item for a match. Something like:

```
var desiredResults = $scope.array.reduce(function(p,c){
    for(key in c){
        if(c[key].indexOf("valueToMatch") > -1){
            p.push(c);
            next();
        }
    }
    return p;
},[])
```

I have not tested this code, but it's the general idea.